# Why is the orthogonal complement actually orthogonal to the projection?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, vector-analysis, projection

How do you show that $q=x-p$ is orthogonal to the projection ($p$)? I can understand it intuitively from drawing it out. But can't show it's true with proof.

What I know is we will have to show that the dot product of $x-p$ and $p$ is $0$. And if I can do that I can show that the angle between them is $90$ degrees. I just don't know how to show this algebraically? Please help. This is the definition for vector projection that I was given:

Let $x$ and $y$ be vectors in $ \mathbb{R}^2$ (or in $ \mathbb{R}^3$ ) with $y \ne 0$. Let $u = \frac{1}{||y||} y$
be the unit vector in the direction of y. Then we define the **vector projection** of **x** onto **y** is $p=\alpha u = \frac{x^Ty}{y^Ty} y$, where $\alpha$ is the **scalar projection** which is defined as $\alpha = \frac{x^Ty}{||y||} $

Nowhere in the definition does it directly say that projection is perpendicular.
I'm think if I can somehow show that $p^Tq=0 $ then I would have solved the problem. I tried substituting in $(x-p)$ in for $q$ and I subbed in $\frac{x^Ty}{y^Ty} y$  for $ p$. I am now stuck.

Comment: By definition of orthogonal projection, $x - \mathrm{pr}_{\langle p \rangle}(x)$ is orthogonal to $p.$

Comment: @WilliamM. But if your given a formula for vector projection how can this be shown?

Comment: Usually you start with some vector $x$ and a vector $v$ you want to project it onto, and you end up with a projected vector. You say "$p$ which is the projection of $x$ onto $p$" but that implies that you already had the answer $p$ before you applied any formulas. So the steps would be to clearly and carefully write down the problem you start with and clearly and carefully write down the formulas you are using, making sure that each symbol means exactly one thing everywhere. Now there should be some expression equal to $p$, plug it into $(x-p)\cdot p$ and evaluate.

Comment: If you are still stuck, show your work so that someone has a chance to get you unstuck. You'll have to edit the question so it shows the formulas you use in a way people can read and understand, so use MathJax, which you can start learning here: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: The way I motivated the projection in one my lectures went along the lines: "we want to find a scalar multiple of $p$ representing the projection of $x$ onto the subspace engendered by $p.$ Geometric intuiton [draw a right-triangle!] suggests that such a projection $x' = \mathrm{pr}(x) = \lambda p$ must satisfy $x - x' \perp p,$ so that $p \cdot (x - x') = p(x - \lambda p) = 0,$ so that $\lambda = p \cdot x / p \cdot p.$" Of course then, _by definition_, $x - x' \perp p.$

Comment: I've updated my post to fully reflect my problem and show my work.

Answer (score 4):

For the inner product I prefer the notation $(\vec x\cdot \vec y)$  instead of $x^Ty$. So, using the linearity of the inner product and the definition of projection
$$
\vec p=\frac{(\vec x\cdot\vec y)}{(\vec y\cdot\vec y)}\vec y
$$

we have
$$
((\vec x-\vec p)\cdot\vec p)=(\vec x \cdot \vec p)-(\vec p \cdot \vec p)=
$$
$$
\frac{(\vec x\cdot\vec y)}{(\vec y\cdot\vec y)}(\vec x\cdot\vec y)-\frac{(\vec x\cdot\vec y)}{(\vec y\cdot\vec y)}\frac{(\vec x\cdot\vec y)}{(\vec y\cdot\vec y)}(\vec y\cdot\vec y)= 
$$
$$
=\frac{(\vec x\cdot\vec y)^2}{(\vec y\cdot\vec y)}-\frac{(\vec x\cdot\vec y)^2}{(\vec y\cdot\vec y)}=0
$$

Answer (score 3):

So using that the projection matrix onto $v$ is $P=uu^T$ with $u$ a unit vector in the direction of $v$ and we will prove that $Px$ is orthgonal to $x-Px$ directly by calculating $(Px)^T(x-Px)$. To do this we will need to use that $P=P^T$ and $P^2=P$ which are easily verified from the formula given.

We can see that $$(Px)^T(x-Px) = x^TP^T(x-Px)=x^TP^Tx-xP^TPx \\=x^TPx -x^TP^2x=x^TPx-x^TPx=0$$ and therefore $Px$ is orthogonal to $x-Px$.

Answer (score 1):

Using your notation, with $p^Tq$ as the inner product,
if you substituted $x - p$ for $q$ and substituted $\frac{x^Ty}{y^Ty} y$ for $p$
you should have gotten this:

$$ \frac{x^Ty}{y^Ty} y^T \left(x - \frac{x^Ty}{y^Ty} y \right). $$

Linear properties of the inner product imply that if $u,$ $v,$ and $w$ are vectors and $\lambda$ is a scalar, then

$$ u^T (v - \lambda w) = u^T v - \lambda u^T w.$$

Keeping in mind that $\frac{x^Ty}{y^Ty}$ is a scalar, you can apply this fact to
$y^T \left(x - \frac{x^Ty}{y^Ty} y \right),$ after which you should see some further simplifications that you can make.